# How to convert a two column Dataframe into a List of List

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a coordinates dataframe with 2 columns X and Y:

```
X     Y
56    89
59    90
58    95
53    89
56    63
59    78
```

Now i want to create a List of List containing the coord. in this way to perform futher operations:

```
list = [(56, 89), (59, 90), (58, 95), (53, 89),....
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you just want to access the values, you can use `df.values` where `df` is the name of your dataframe. This give a 2D numpy array that can be iterated over like a list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want with your example:

```
[(x, y) for x, y in zip(df["X"].values, df["Y"].values)]
```

`zip` accepts more than two `list`s, so you can easily adapt this code to, say, 3 or more coordinates (or any other column in your dataframe).